# Why external include directory compiles multiple times?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, include, glm-math

When I am making changes to my code, the external files are compiled multiple times. I am using math library glm, and Visual Studio seem to be compiling exactly same glm/vec3.hpp file multiple times. I have included glm header multiple time, and it seems that it doesn't use previously compiled code, but recompiles it again.

For example, in my math.h I have included.

```
#ifndef MATH_HH
#define MATH_HH

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
...
```

And when I am compiling after changes to code, I see that Visual Studio compiles glm/vec3.hpp multiples times. Basically it compiles it each time that it compiles one of my edited files.

For example, the Visual Studio output looks like this:

```
1>C:\test\external\glm\glm\detail\type_vec3.hpp(50,1): warning C4201: nonstandard extension used: nameless struct/union
...
10>own_file.cc
11>C:\test\external\glm\glm\detail\type_vec3.hpp(50,1): warning C4201: nonstandard extension used: nameless struct/union
...
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Or do I need to compile them each time some cpp file uses them? Or am I just confused of Visual Studio's style warnings?

Comment: There is no such file in the GLM project. Can you provide actual build output that mentions this file? Or did you mean `glm/vec3.hpp`?

Comment: Yes, I meant header files. Updated the question to describe the issue in more detail.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Answer (score 0):

> Basically it compiles it each time that it compiles one of my edited files.

That's how C++ works. It compiles source files. Including a header file is just taking the text in that file and dumping it into your source file. Therefore, if you include a header file in 3 source files, the text of that header will be compiled 3 times.

There are precompiled headers (a compiler-specific tool), and the C++20 modules feature, that can avoid this. But outside of those, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: This clears it up, thanks! Can't wait for C++20 to become standard.

Comment: @Toothery: It's already a standard. It's just not common-place as of yet, with many compilers not fully implementing it.